# cambiar la codificación por defecto de ANSI a UTF-8 en Windows server

Tags: windows, utf-8, server

resulta que tengo una necesidad en la cual la codificación por defecto de el block de notas sea UTF-8 y no ANSI como ahora esta. esto es raro por que en las PC de escritorio si es UTF-8 la codificación por defecto pero en los Windows server es ANSI.

Están haciendo un desarrollo en Windows server 2016, al momento de que el "desarrollo" crea un documento lo guarda en ANSI y el sistema que toma ese archivo solo acepta UTF-8.

alguien ha tenido esta necesidad que me pueda echar una mano?

de antemano un millón de gracias.